# Why can't I add pin constraints in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

I'm reading the book "***Learn iOS 8 App Development***". I'm following his steps and here is my problem:

[image: Add New Constraints Pop-up]

He asked to deselect the "***Constrain to margins***". Down this little square he has 4 controls, and I have three (The align, square, and triangle).
Why can't I add 4 constraints as he does? He didn't select nothing and it's written in his computer "***Add 4 constraints***".

Comment: Go to Editor>Pin when to view is selected in IB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to click on each of the four orange I-beams to turn them from dashed to solid.  Then the button will change to <kbd>Add 4 Constraints</kbd>.

[image: Add4Constraints]